# how to parse a page that is going on 302 header?

Tags: php, parsing, http-status-code-302

i have to parse a page in php,the url of the page is going on 302 Moved temporarily header and is moved to a not found page.Its data can be retrieved manually through console option of firebug add on of mozilla.But if i try to parse it using php it gives me that not found page in return.How can i parse that page please suggest??

edit:
iam doing something like this to get the page's content

```
$file_results = @fopen("http://www.the url to be parses","rb");
    $parsed_results='';
    if($file_results)
    {
        while ($data3 = fread($file_results,"125000"))
        $parsed_results .= $data3;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_headers()](http://php.net/get_headers) to find all the headers while you're being redirected.

```
$url = 'http://google.com';
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);

print 'First step gave: ' . $headers[0] . '<br />';

// uncomment below to see the different redirection URLs
// print_r($headers['Location']);

// $headers['Location'] will contain either the redirect URL, or an array
// of redirection URLs
$first_redirect_url = isset($headers['Location'][0]) ?
    $headers['Location'][0] : $headers['Location'];

print "First redirection is to: {$first_redirect_url}<br />";

// assuming you have fopen wrappers enabled...
print file_get_contents($first_redirect_url);
```

And just keep looking till you get the resource you want?

Comment: ya but this is not what i want....see i want the content of the very first page not of the redirected page

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the header, see where it is redirecting you, and make another request to get the actual resource. Kind of a pain, but thats how the protocol works. Most browsers do this transparently.

Comment: i would really appreciate if you can quote some example

Comment: what method did you use to make the request in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to do this in php, but that is the general idea of how you can get the actual resource.